# OpenFlutter/flutter_oktoast shows on main page only?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using [this](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_oktoast) library to show custom toast in my app. I have multiple pages in my app. The problem is, toast appears on the main page even when I call `showToastWidget(...)` from any other pages.

**Main Page**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OKToast(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/ic_logo.png')),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Page 2**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OKToast(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Reset Password'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showToastWidget(
                  Text('Hello. I am Toast!!!'),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Show'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I call `showToastWidget(...)` from this page, it appears on Main Page

**EDIT 1**
I get this exception when I pass context to `showToastWidget()`

```
I/flutter (24327): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (24327): The getter 'position' was called on null.
I/flutter (24327): Receiver: null
I/flutter (24327): Tried calling: position
I/flutter (24327): 
I/flutter (24327): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (24327): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (24327): #1      showToastWidget (package:oktoast/src/toast.dart:210:40)
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you wrapping your page's scaffold in an OKToast widget?

Comment: That's what it says on their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `OKToast` library does not support multiple `OKToast` widgets in the same app. You will have to wrap your entire app in an `OKToast` widget, full sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:oktoast/oktoast.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OKToast(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Show"),
              onPressed: () {
                showToast(
                  "Main Page toast",
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Go to next page"),
              onPressed: () => _goToNextPage(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _goToNextPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Second Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showToast(
                "Second Page toast",
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              );
            },
            child: Text('Show'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get exception [here](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_oktoast/blob/35af283d599e2650ead5b5670bf75f6b8858939d/lib/src/toast.dart#L159) Please see my updated question to see log

Comment: I updated my answer. Looks like the library doesn't support multiple OKToast widgets so you will have to wrap your entire app in one.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of OKToast, I am very glad that you use this library.

This tip of Toast is based on the design of toast in android on the mobile side.
The inspiration for OKToast itself comes from toast, so it is inevitable that it has received an impact, not adapting to the individual page-level Toast.

If you need a page-level OKToast component, you might need to do this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:oktoast/oktoast.dart';
import 'package:simple_widget/simple_widget.dart';

class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoryPageState createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OKToast(
      child: SimpleScaffold(
        title: "CategoryPage",
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (ctx) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.trip_origin),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showToast("page toast", context: ctx); // use context to show toast in the page-level OKToast.
                  },
                ),
          ),
        ],
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: SimpleScaffold is a simple wrapper of Scaffold.